# Check if a C# string is a well formed url with a port number

Tags: c#, uri

I got a string which I check if it represents a URL like this:

```
if(Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(urlString, UriKind.Absolute)) ...
```

Is there also a way to add there a check if the url contains a port number?

Comment: You need to create an object of Uri class by passing the urlString to it's constructor and then access objects Port property to get the port number of the URL

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya but it's an int and not even an int? so if it was not supplied it would be 0 or something else?

Comment: If the url does not have any port specified in it then I think the port number will be based on the protocol. For http it will be 80 and for https it will be 443. You can read the documentation and also try experiment with code for different url values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could offload all the heavy work to the Uri constructor:

```
var uri = new Uri(urlString);
```

Then you only need to interpret `uri.Authority`. If it contains a colon, the port is specified.

```
public static bool IncludesPort(this string urlAddress)
{
    return new Uri(urlAddress).Authority.Contains(':');
}
```

Comment: It won't have any issues with urls in the form of: http://username:password@example.com/    ?    I don't know how to highlight code and urls in comments so its start with http there as well

Comment: No, `new Uri("http://username:password@example.com").Authority` returns "example.com"

Answer (score -1):

```
public class StackoverflowQuestion
{
    public string Run() {
        string urlString = "http://mywebsite:8001/application/api";
        if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(urlString, UriKind.Absolute) && urlString.IncludesPort())
            return "The uri contains explicitly defined port";
        return "";
    }
}

public static class Extensions { 
    public static bool IncludesPort(this string urlAddress)
    {
        urlAddress = urlAddress.Replace("http://", "").Replace("https://", "");
        var splitted = urlAddress.Split(':');
        var port = splitted?[1].Split("/")?[0];
        return port != null && int.TryParse(port, out _);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is restricted (unneccessarily) to http and https. Also it will have problems wit URLs of the form `http://username:password@example.com/`